# Unicity statement of Radon-Nikodym derivative

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $f \in \mathcal{L}^1(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ be such that $\mu(\mathbb{1}_E f)=0$ for all $E \in \Sigma$.

With this information, I want to prove that $\mu(\{ f \neq 0 \}) = 0$.

I know that
\begin{align}
\mu(\mathbb{1}_E f)=0 \text{ for all $E \in \Sigma$} \implies \mathbb{1}_E f=0 \text{ for all $E \in \Sigma$}
\end{align}
and that
\begin{align}
\nu(\{ f \neq 0 \}) = \int_{\{ f \neq 0 \}} f\ d\mu = \mu(\mathbb{1}_{\{ f \neq 0 \}}\cdot f) = 0.
\end{align}
How to conclude that $\mu(\{ f \neq 0 \}) =0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First consider the case $E = \{f>0 \}$. If $\mu(E) \neq 0$, then $\mu(f \mathbb{1}_E) \neq 0$ (the integral of a strictly positive function over a non-null set cannot be $0$). But by assumption, $\mu(f \mathbb{1}_E) = 0$. Therefore, $\mu(E)=0$.

The case $E = \{ f< 0 \}$ is similar.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
Consider $E=\{ f > 0\}$ and $E=\{ f < 0\}$.